# JSpdf using size of data is longer than page width so that displayed text is fit in page and ignoring the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, jspdf

I am using the `Jspdf` script in order to convert the HTML form to a PDF file. It is converted to a PDF file but size of data is longer than page width so that displayed text had fit on the page and ignores the rest.

[image: Screenshot]

**My Code**:

```js
$("#save-img").on("click", function () {
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    // Source HTMLElement or a string containing HTML.
    var elementHTML = document.querySelector("#Saftyinspecmodal");

    doc.html(elementHTML, {
        callback: function (doc) {
            // Save the PDF
            doc.save("document-html.pdf");
        },
        // Adjust your margins here (left, top, right ,bottom)
        //margin: [0, 0, 40, 0],
        //autoPaging: 'text',
        //x: 0,
        //y: 0,
        //width: doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth(), //target width in the PDF document
        //windowWidth: 1000 //window width in CSS pixels
    });
});
```

Comment: html2pdf not working generating blank pdf file